# Popup Background honours light/dark theme?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have the following in my XAML and this works great with the dark theme.  When I switch the the white/light theme it changes the text colour but not the background.  Removing the Background property from the border just makes it transparent.

Can anyone help?

```
<Popup x:Name="PinDetailsPopup" Margin="45,0,28,94" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Opacity="0.75" >
                        <Popup.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </Popup.RenderTransform>
                        <Border Height="70" Width="400" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="2" Background="#CA000000" >
                            <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedPin}">

                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding flightno, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding route, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,30,0,-22"/>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding feet, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,30,0,0"/>
                                <Button Click="detailsClick" Content="More" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the theme resources, they will automatically adjust based on the users theme choice. They are detailed here.

[Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly setting the background color (to "#CA000000") were you expecting this to be overriddden by the Framework/OS?

Either set a color that works in both themes or change the color depending on the selected theme.

You'll find advice on detecting the current theme at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-phone-7%5D+detect+theme

Comment: It does on other platforms such as Droid and iPhone!

Comment: @Lee you've downvoted my description of how it works because it works differently to other platforms? Seriously? I didn't know that Android and iOS had comparable theming techniques.

Comment: back to 0.  Matt is right, on windows (of any flavor) if you use a specific color, you get that specific color all the time.  If you use a theme color, you get whatever the color is in the theme... that's kindof the point of using themes...